# Keybind causes function to run automatically on startup

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to create a keybind for my `Entry`, which takes what the user has inputted into the `Entry` and then calls a function.

**My code:**

```
def nameValidation(name):
    if PresenceCheck(name) and LengthCheck(name,2) and DataTypeCheck(name,str):
        print("Valid Name")
    else:
        nameEntry.configure(bg="red")
nameEntry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=nameInput,bg="white",font=("Arial",28))
nameEntry.grid(row=2,column=2)
nameEntry.bind("<FocusOut>",nameValidation(nameInput.get()))
```

When I run the code, the `Entry` is coloured red, indicating the function has been called, even though the keybind was not activated.

Comment: in the last line you're calling the function instead of referencing it as a callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake. Your function is executing on the execution of your program, because you have called it with parentheses in your `.bind()`.

A way to fix this would be to add a [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).

Code:

```py
def nameValidation(name, event = None):
    if PresenceCheck(name) and LengthCheck(name,2) and DataTypeCheck(name,str):
        print("Valid Name")
    else:
        nameEntry.configure(bg="red")
nameEntry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=nameInput,bg="white",font=("Arial",28))
nameEntry.grid(row=2,column=2)
nameEntry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda: nameValidation(nameInput.get()))
```

Hope this helps!

---

As stated in the comments, use `lambda: event` if you want the anonymous function. If you get an error with that, use `lambda _:`

Comment: This will throw an error all the binds pass an event argument to the first parameter of the callback function.

Comment: @Saad Thanks for pointing out that error. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Here the callback function is the anonymous function lambda not `nameValidation`, it should be `lambda event: ... `

Comment: @Saad I get this error with your solution in the line def nameValidation(event = None, name):
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Comment: or just `lambda _: ...` if you're not using the argument

Comment: Also, `nameValidation(event = None, name)` this will give an error. You can't give a default parameter before a normal parameter

Comment: @Saad I am sorry! I think I am sleepy, let me edit my answer.